# Как сделать запрос с передачей нескольких параметров?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server, ado.net

Добавил `ListBox` на WinForm (там изменил `SelectionMode=MultiSimple`). Для выбора несколько услуг. Сейчас визуальный выбор несколько услуг выбирается, но при выборе он суммирует только 1 услугу. И еще в данный момент есть ошибка если не выбрана ни одна из услуг (System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта"), но это видимо из-за исключения ToString. Но самое важное, как правильно сделать суммирование всех выбранных услуг + цена 1 комнаты?

Нужно правильно суммировать 2 услуги сразу, а не только одну.

```
// Запрос к таблице услуг
private void GetAdditionalServices()
{
    Con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT* FROM AdditionalServicesTbl", Con);
    SqlDataReader rdr;
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ServicesNum", typeof(int));
    dt.Load(rdr);
    listBox1.ValueMember = "ServicesNum";
    listBox1.DataSource = dt;
    Con.Close();
}

// Получаем счет за (услугу-тут проблема) + счет за комнату
int Price = 0;
int PriceServices = 0;

private void fetchCostServices()
{
    Con.Open();
    string Query = "SELECT ServicesCost FROM AdditionalServicesTbl where ServicesNum=" + listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, Con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        PriceServices = CONVERT.ToInt32(dr["ServicesCost"].ToString());
    }
    Con.Close();
}

private void fetchCostRooms()
{
    Con.Open();
    string Query = "SELECT TypeCost FROM RoomTbl join TypeTbl on RType=TypeNum where RNum="
        + RoomCb.SelectedValue.ToString() + "";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, Con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Price = CONVERT.ToInt32(dr["TypeCost"].ToString());
    }
    Con.Close();
}

// Кол-во дней прожживание в гостинице (цена 1 комнаты + цена 1 услуги = общая сумма (цена комнаты + цена всех выбранных услуг)
private void DurationTb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AmountTb.Text == "")
    {
        AmountTb.Text = " 0";
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            int Total = Price * CONVERT.ToInt32(DurationTb.Text) + PriceServices * CONVERT.ToInt32(DurationTb.Text);
            AmountTb.Text = "" + Total;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это что за язык? Похож на шарп, только ключевые слова почему-то большими буквами. Этот код не скомпилируется.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: /это с# + sql Но я не могу понять, как суммировать сразу две услуги?! Получилось реализовать сумму 1 услуги + 1 номера. Хочу  множество услуг + 1 номер. Добавил listbox на winform (там изменил selectionMode=MultiSimple.
Может быть, вы могли бы помочь?! @aepot

Comment: Не пишите дополнительную информацию в комментариях, пишите в сам вопрос. Комментарии тяжело читать, особенно с кодом в них. Помочь не смогу, не шарю в ADO.NET

Comment: @aepot изменил описание.спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, в листбоксе можно выбрать несколько значений. А может быть и ни одного не выбрано. Нужно это проверять в начале метода.

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    return;
```

Далее, нужно получить из листбокса выбранные значения и вставить их в sql-запрос.

```
string format = "SELECT ServicesCost FROM AdditionalServicesTbl WHERE ServicesNum in ({0})";
string values = string.Join(",", listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<DataRowView>().Select(row => row[0]));
string query = string.Format(format, values);
```

К листбоксу прибинден дататейбл, поэтому в коллекции `SelectedItems` находятся `DataRowView`. Извлекаем их и берём значение первой (она же единственная) колонки (с индексом 0).

Если уж вы решили использовать `DataTable`, то знайте, что `SqlDataAdapter` способен сам открыть соединение, создать внутри себя `SqlCommand` и выполнить запрос.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
sda.Fill(dt);
```

После чего суммируем полученные из БД данные:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    PriceServices += row.Field<int>("ServicesCost");
}
```

Обратите внимание на `+=`.

Полный код метода может выглядеть так:

```
private void FetchCostServices()
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        return;

    string format = "SELECT ServicesCost FROM AdditionalServicesTbl WHERE ServicesNum in ({0})";
    string values = string.Join(",", listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<DataRowView>().Select(row => row[0]));
    string query = string.Format(format, values);

    var dt = new DataTable();
    var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
    sda.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        PriceServices += row.Field<int>("ServicesCost");
    }
}
```

Но если нужна только сумма, то её можно и нужно посчитать прямо в БД. Пример в своём ответе показал Vitaliy Zlobin.

Для получения одного значения из БД нет смысла использовать `DataTable`. Применим метод `ExecuteScalar`.

```
private void FetchCostServices()
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        return;

    string format = "SELECT SUM(ServicesCost) FROM AdditionalServicesTbl WHERE ServicesNum in ({0})";
    string values = string.Join(",", listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<DataRowView>().Select(row => row[0]));
    string query = string.Format(format, values);

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            PriceServices = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на применение `using` - это автоматически освободит ресурсы. Соединение при этом закроется тоже само, вызывать `Close` не нужно.
Не делайте `SqlConnection` полем класса. Создавайте его прямо по месту.

---

Я не знаю точные типы ваших данных, поэтому замените при необходимости `int` на правильные типы в вызовах `OfType`, `Field` и при касте.

---

Правильнее было бы сделать, чтобы метод возвращал значение: `private int FetchCostServices()`, вместо использования поля класса.

Ещё хорошо бы использовать асинхронность, но это отдельная тема. Задайте новый вопрос, если есть желание вникнуть.

Comment: Спасибо большое @Alexander Petrov.Очень интересное решение.Да про асинхронность было б круто услышать System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Incorrect syntax near ')'." PriceServices = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); на данный момент при выборе одной либо более услуг вылазит эта ошибка(а если использовать первый метоод такая же ошибка,но на другую строчку sda.Fill(dt); в чем может быть проблема и как это можно испрвавить ?!

Comment: @checka12351 - см. update. Исправил `OfType`.

Comment: не могли бы еще помочь,чтобы при записи в бд,показало все выбранные записи из списка,а не только одну запись в данный момент ? @Alexander Petrov

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать метод, который даст тебе список всех услуг, вида:

'Услуга1', 'Услуга2' и т.д.

Затем изменить этот запрос:

```
SELECT ServicesCost FROM AdditionalServicesTbl where ServicesNum=" + listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "
```

на:

```
SELECT SUM(ServicesCost) FROM AdditionalServicesTbl where servicesNum IN (" + ServicesList + ")";
```